# How to rotate or transform tableView cell's image

Tags: iphone, memory-management, uitableview, uiimage

I am supposed to show a lot of images(horizontally one after another) like a gallery in my iPad app. The number of images can vary from 10 to 500 and even more. So, i though of using a tableView to display the images as it helps me to create as less objects as posible. I have created a tableView and rotated it by 90 degrees using CGAffineTransform. Now, i am supposed to rotate even the images to compensate for the rotation of tableView. This is where i am getting struck. I know that i can put my image into a imageView and transform the imageview before assigning it to the tableView cell. But, this would not serve the purpose as this needs a large number of imageViews which would consume a lot of memory.

**My questions are**

**1 - how can i rotate my image before or after assigning it to the tableView cell without using a imageView**

**2 - Is there any other way in which the above senario can be implemented efficiently with minimum memory consumption**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to rotate the `UITableViewCell` to compensate the rotation of the `UITableView` (also using `CGAffineTransform`).

I did it once and worked very well.

Comment: Haha... i'm waiting to give you more than that... just hold on for some time... bliv me itz worth the wait...

Comment: Hey Raphael, just another doubt. I have transformed the cell and in process even the cell's accessory view got transformed as well. Now, can i once again the transform only the accessoryView ??? Eagerly waiting for ur reply

Comment: haha no problem. I believe that in this case the best thing to do is create your own UITableViewCell subclass, with a subview that works as the accessoryView and other subviews. In my case I did it. If it's simple and won't have too much subviews, instead of creating a subclass just add a subviews that workds as the accessoryView,

Comment: in this case, i would be creating as many number of objects as my subviews which will be again a memory constrain.... wont this be a problem?

Comment: Yes, it is. That fact is that the UITableViewCell doesn't allow you to change the position of some of its subview (accessoryView or editingAccessoryView for example). Then subviews could help you. Consider also the creation of sublayers to the cell layer (for the cases you don't need a UIResponder), instead of subviews. It can help to improve memory usage.

Comment: Thanks for all the help from u rapheal.... As promised to u +1 + accpt... Hope this kind of help would continue from you even in future...